# React native twitter sign in

Tags: react-native, twitter-login

I installed twitter login for react native and I get this error on

```
apply plugin: 'Crashlytics' from your library project. If you're looking for Library support, please contact support@fabric.io
:react-native-twitter-signin:generateReleaseResValues
:react-native-twitter-signin:generateReleaseResources
:react-native-twitter-signin:mergeReleaseResources
:react-native-twitter-signin:processReleaseResources
:react-native-twitter-signin:generateReleaseSources
:react-native-twitter-signin:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:react-native-twitter-signin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:react-native-twitter-signin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
/Users/khalidahmada/www/travelStory/node_modules/react-native-twitter-signin/android/src/main/java/com/goldenowl/twittersignin/TwitterSigninModule.java:32: error: TwitterSigninModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNewIntent(Intent) in ActivityEventListener
public class TwitterSigninModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
       ^
/Users/khalidahmada/www/travelStory/node_modules/react-native-twitter-signin/android/src/main/java/com/goldenowl/twittersignin/TwitterSigninModule.java:88: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
2 errors
:react-native-twitter-signin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

Any idea about this error? I'm JavaScript Developer and I have no idea about this error.

This is the node module:
[react-native-twitter-signin](https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin)

Comment: did you do `react-native link`?

Comment: Yes. i also verified.

Answer (score 1):

delete `@override` at selected file .code will work fine...